# Ошибка при загрузке файла

Tags: php, html, upload

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/fun/editcontact.php' method='post'>
<td style='border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;'><span style='display: inline-block;margin-left:10px;margin-right:15px;'><i style='margin-right:15px; font-size:20px; color:#737373;' class='far fa-image'></i>Фото: </span><input style='border-bottom: 0px solid #737373;float:right;height:auto;margin-right: -25px; name='userfile' type='file'><input type='hidden' name='file_name' value='".$row['id']."'><input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='3000000'></td>
</form>
```

И php:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = '/home/uploads/contacts/';
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_POST['file_name'] . '.jpg'))
{
    print "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";
} else {
    print "There some errors!";
}
header("Location: *");
?>
```

Когда заливаю файл eror log выдает такую ошибку.

[05-Nov-2018 08:23:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userfile in /home/editcontact.php on line 16

[05-Nov-2018 08:23:49 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: userfile in /home/editcontact.php on line 17
В чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо.

Comment: а какая линия 16 и 17?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['userfile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $_POST['file_name'] . '.jpg'))

Comment: Смотрите что в $_FILES. Будет понятно какие там ключи.

Comment: @MAX что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Имеется в виду выведите `$_FILES` и глазками своими посмотрите какие в нем значения.

Comment: Также у вас потеряна половина кавычек в значениях атрибутов, вероятно html выводится не так как вы ожидаете. К тому же оборачивать `td` в тег `form` тоже не допускается, браузер перестраивает ваш html в более-менее валидный и вот на выходе совсем не то что вы выводите.

Comment: @u_mulder это html код находиться в echo другого php скрипта

Comment: И что - это делает его валидным?

Comment: @u_mulder да, в другом php скрипте аналогично сделано и загрузка происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При загрузке фалов ошибка `PHP Notice: Undefined index: *** in` возникает когда не определен массив $_FILES, ошибка напрямую об этом говорит. Добавьте input/button `type="submit"` для отправки формы в action